# How to adjust column text to bind data value to adequate column of barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot that kind of data using this code:

```
ammount <- c(1000, 3000, 1000, 5000, 4000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 4500, 5000, 1500, 6000)
area <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
type <- c("incoming","incoming","incoming","incoming","incoming","incoming", 
          "outgoing", "outgoing", "outgoing", "outgoing", "outgoing", "outgoing")

df <- data.frame(area, ammount, type)

library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(scales)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(area, ammount), ammount,
             group = type,
             fill = type))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma_format(big.mark = ".",
                                           decimal.mark = ","))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1, 
                                   hjust=1))+
  geom_text(aes(label = ammount), 
            size = 3, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  coord_flip()
```

what I got is this plot:

[image]

My question is:

1. how to adjust column text (or labels) to bind right value to adequate column,
2. how to format text to make it visible,
3. is it possible to use other package than ggplot.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Find my solution below,
   in   `geom_text(..., position, ...)` use `position_dodge(0.905)` as the value for `position` argument

`theme()` is irrelevant in your code as `vjust=1, hjust=1` which are already default values.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(area, ammount), ammount,
             group = type,
             fill = type))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma_format(big.mark = ".",
                                           decimal.mark = ",")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ammount), 
            size = 3, 
            position = position_dodge(0.905)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

2. `geom_text()` has other parameters such as `color, alpha` to change the colour and visibility of the tex

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(area, ammount), ammount,
             group = type,
             fill = type))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1, hjust=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma_format(big.mark = ".",
                                           decimal.mark = ",")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ammount), 
            size = 3, 
            position = position_dodge(0.8),
            color = 'darkblue',
            alpha = 1) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]
More documentation can be found [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html)

3. `ggplot2` is probably the best package for this task, but you might consider `plotly` and `dygraph` especially if you need interactive plot.